# Low Level Network Traffic Access on iOS Device

Tags: ios, iphone, networking, proxy, vpn

I'm looking for a way to develop an iOS in which I can access all network traffic, (I mean System-Wide) and route it through my app. Something like a proxy server but notice that I want to force the route and access all the traffic not only web requests (Something like what VPN Connections do).

I think that may go a bit beyond Apple limitations regarding `App Store Guidelines`. Any VPN API accessible for doing that ? Any **practical suggestion** or description on undocumented and private APIs is really appreciated.

P.S: [This article](http://blog.michael.kuron-germany.de/2010/09/ios-4-1-undocumented-vpn-api-used-by-cisco-anyconnect/) may help understanding what I'm looking for;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Network Extension of iOS9 will allow custom VPN tunnel implementations and NEPacketTunnelProvider is probably what you are looking for.

Check out the WWDC video.
https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=717

You need to send an email to apple to get access to this function.
https://github.com/shadowsocks/shadowsocks-iOS/issues/124

Answer (score 5):

To be able to do VPN functionalities you have to create a vpnplugin, the problem is that it's a pseudo-Private API, I'm saying "pseudo" because there are companies that had access to the documentation and there are apps on the App Store that uses it (OpenVPN connect for example). You can try reverse engineering some of those app plugins (it's the folder with the .vpnplugin extension).

By the way, someone already did that and published the vpn plugin API to github: https://github.com/Smartype/iOS_VPNPlugIn/blob/master/iOSVPNPlugIn.h